# Instance level access control in Apache Shiro

Tags: java, shiro

I found really a flexible security framework Apache Shiro. I successfully implemented authentication and authorization using Shiro.

One of appealing features of the framework is instance based security. I just copied example from Shiro website.

The following permissions are stored in the database.

```
printer:query:lp7200
printer:print:epsoncolor
```

The following code check if for a given printer instance, the current authenticated user has permission or not.

```
if ( SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("printer:query:lp7200") {
 // Return the current jobs on printer lp7200
}
```

My question is that "Is this how permissions are stored in database?"
Is there a better way to store instance based permissions?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How you store this information is entirely up to you.  Your `Realm` implementation is responsible for querying whatever datasource you're using and extracting permission data in the format you prefer.

Some people store them as strings directly (like those shown in your example), other people store them in a dedicated table (e.g. if using an RDBMS) (e.g. permission_type, target, action columns).  You can associate the permission entities to roles or directly to users or to groups which are assigned to users, etc - however it makes sense for your application.

Your storage options are entirely up to you.  You materialize the data however you wish to ensure the `Realm.isPermitted(...)` operations function as expected.

Instead of implementing the `Realm.isPermitted(...)` methods directly, many people find it more convenient to subclass the abstract `AuthorizingRealm` class and override the `doGetAuthorizationInfo` method and return `AuthorizationInfo` instances that support permission representations.

In that method, you could query your datastore, translate the data returned into `AuthorizationInfo` instances, and you'll be done (don't forget to enable authorization caching - you'll see a big performance benefit).

Overriding the `Realm` `isPermitted` methods is only necessary if you want very specific control over queries, etc.